# NUnit System.NullReferenceException Makes No Sense

Tags: c#, maven, nunit

While I am familiar with JUnit, I am less familiar with NUnit. My (SIMPLE) test is failing and I cannot make sense of it.

```
[INFO]  | NUnit-Console version 2.6.3.13283
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
[INFO]  | Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
[INFO]  | All Rights Reserved.
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | Runtime Environment -
[INFO]  |    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
[INFO]  |   CLR Version: 2.0.50727.8000 ( Net 3.5 )
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
[INFO]  | Execution Runtime: net-3.5
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | Tests run: 1, Errors: 1, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.130717193180073 seconds
[INFO]  |   Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  | Errors and Failures:
[INFO]  | 1) Test Error : net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate.ElevateTest.NoArguments
[INFO]  |    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[INFO]  |    at net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate.Elevate.Main(String[] commandArguments)
[INFO]  |    at net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate.ElevateTest.NoArguments()
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  |
[INFO]  +--[ FAILED, result = 1, error output = false]
```

My actual test code is

```
[Test]
public void NoArguments()
{
    String [] arguments = new String[0];

    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, arguments);

    var result = Elevate.Main(arguments);

    Assert.Equals(0, result);
}
```

and my code under test starts with

```
public static int Main(string[] commandArguments)
{
    if (commandArguments == null) return 0;
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where the NullReferenceException is coming from.

What is even crazier is that at some point this test was passing fine, so now I have no idea what is going on. If it is any relevance, I am running the test using Maven with NPanday.

Comment: Is it possible that the error is farther along inside the Main method, and has nothing to do with the commandArguments parameter?  The best thing to do would be step-through debug by building in debug and attaching your debugger to the nunit console app.

Comment: commandArguments is not passed as null in the test you show and 0 will not be returned from the section of Main you show, so something else is amiss. Set the Debugger to Break on Exceptions and you might get better information.

Answer (score 0):

OK, multiple problems here:

1. Getting the right instances of NUnit configured. I am using SharpDevelop instead of Visual Studio, and I had to remove the reference to the internal version of NUnit, and point to the latest installed version. Since I am using Maven/NPanday to build my project, many things do not work as nice as Maven with Java.
2. Subtle change in code related to array references. I moved some code around, and of course the logic changed. I was trying to access commandArguments[0] when the length was 0.
3. I have been spoiled using Java for so many years. I keep forgetting that 'everything' in .NET or MicrosoftLand is harder. For instance, in Java a stacktrace comes with line numbers by default. In .NET you have to spend hours of research trying to figure out how to make this work.
4. My particular program runs with elevated privileges, so normal debugging is off limits.

After fixing all these problems, my code and tests finally work, well mostly work. Now I have to figure out how to get .NET to terminate my theads--oh how I miss Java already.

Thanks Rick and RJ, your comments really did help.

Comment: Re #3: In .NET, the stack trace should have line numbers if you have compiled in Debug mode and the .pdb files are in the same folder as the dll.